Matrix Multiplication using a Neural Network
As I understand Neural Networks they have a slow training phase (quadratic or cubic time) and a fast (linear time) inference phase.
Also, the slow training phase comes from the requirement of doing matrix multiplications for which fast exact algorithms are not possible.
Question

Were there any experiments before, where people tried to build a Neural Network to achieve approximate fixed size Matrix Multiplication?
Is it possible to train a Neural Network for calculating fixed size matrix multiplication and using this Neural Network Model (which then has fast inference) for training a second Neural Network (which then has fast inference and training)?


matrix multiplication are not the bottleneck of NNs

That's the first time I hear this... "The bottleneck for deep neural networks is matrix multiply. [...] As a result, any good deep learning system must
involve efficient matrix multiplication." https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4787/2019sp/notes/lecture11.pdf

one thing is theory, another one is practice. matmul, and even more nn forward pass, are embarrassingly parallelizable, try fitting a GP with matrix inversion, or a KNN calculating the distances, and you’ll realize what i mean :)

I don't think that a few SIMD operations will make a more-than-quadratic runtime complexity become linear runtime. If MatMul is not the bottleneck for NNs, what is it in your opinion?

AlphaTensor by DeepMind is likely the most notable attempt to speed up matrix multiplication using AI.
As a note on the second question, likely the advancement here would be to attempt to analyze what the network is doing and build a rule set from it.  Running a neural network is faster than training it but nowhere near as fast as if we can translate it’s logic to rules.

So, basically the approach could work and could make it faster?

DeepMind has shown evidence that this may be possible.  Paper is a year or two old and I'm not sure if any other researchers have explored the methods presented or the problem further.
